# Selenium C# Don't want to keep creating a new instance of FireFoxDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instance, specflow

I am currently trying to create some automation tests for a website, I am having one issue which is whenever I call my base class it creates a new instance of the FirefoxDriver. So whenever I call a page in my steps which inherits the base class it loads a new instance of the driver so it is no longer automating on the previous driver.

```
namespace RAA_AutomationTests
{
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

    public abstract class BasePage
    {
        protected static IWebDriver driver;

        protected BasePage()
        {
            //cant keep creating a new driver need to change this
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        public void click(By locator)
        {
            Find(locator).Click();
        }

        public IWebElement Find(By locator)
        {
            //ValidateSelector(locator); will update css selectors, however not to cause any extra delays by checking this programmatically.

            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));

            return driver.FindElement(locator);
        }
    }
}
```

This is all the code inside of my base class I just need to find a way of using the already open driver instead of creating a new one.
I have a hooks file which opens the browser for me so I just need the driver in the base class to use that one.

Comment: "hooks file which opens the browser for me" means is this another class which open firefox by selenium?

Comment: yes i have another file which opens the browser using [BeforeScenario] i am only using the base class for the click and wait functions but i need to tell it which driver to use inorder for it to work.

Comment: You are inheriting base class at pages so it will create Firefox object every time when you create object of Page class. So good approach separate you browser configuration method from page and it should be at test class level not page class level.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Java perspective, let's say I have one class which open the browser

```
public class Hook {

public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void startBrowser(){

    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
}

}
```

To use this browser in another class, simply i inherit it to other classes and i will not initiate any drivers in those.

public class TestClass extends Hook {

```
@Test
public void toNavigate(){
    driver.get("http://www.myurl.com");
}

}
```

The alternative way is to create one method in Hook which returns driver and need to collect that driver in another classes

something like this in Hook

```
  public WebDriver startBrowser(){

    return driver=new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

getting this driver in other classes

```
 public class TestClass {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void toNavigate(){
    Hook h=new Hook();
    driver=h.startBrowser();
    driver.get("http://www.myurl.com");
}

}
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: let i have simple testcase how u are calling these classes.. looks all are well here and good to use startBrowser and BeforeScenario different classes as one is reusable method and another is which is to start before execution. in java we generally extends this BeforeScenario to other classes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of the Page objects (it's a major violation of the [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), but I think that your design can use a bit different approach. Take a look at the Selenium's home [page examples](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern):

```
 /**
 * Page Object encapsulates the Home         Page
 */
  public class HomePage {

    private WebDriver selenium;

    public HomePage(WebDriver selenium) {
            if (!selenium.getTitle().equals("Home Page of logged in user")) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("This is not Home Page of logged in user, current page" +
                                    "is: " +selenium.getLocation());
            }
    }

    public HomePage manageProfile() {
            // Page encapsulation to manage profile functionality
            return new HomePage(selenium);
    }

    /*More methods offering the services     represented by Home Page
    of Logged User. These methods in   turn might return more Page Objects
    for example click on Compose mail  button could return ComposeMail class object*/

 }
```

As you can see there is no reason to keep a static instance in your Pages, instead you could utilize [IoC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and a [Constructor DI](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection) for the WebDriver object.

If I had to do it, I would create the Driver via [Factory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), put the actions(click, type etc.) in Actions class and keep Pages clean of such logic as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to create a webdrive instance in another place and pass it to your base class via constructor.

So in a Test class you should create a new driver (perhaps in SetUp fixture) and pass it to constructor of your base class:

```
driver = new FireFoxDriver();
BasePage base = new BasePage(driver);
```

**In your base class the constructor should be:**

```
public class BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
{
   this.driver = driver;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

**Also consider the more heavy but maybe better way** - create WebDriver Factory. How to do it using C# is shown here: https://github.com/FriendlyTester/WebDriverFactoryExample/blob/master/WebDriverDriverFactory/WebDriverDriverFactory/WebDriverFactory.cs